# Script for removing rows in Google sheets

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets, rows, google-forms

I'm in need of a script that removes, not just deleting, rows in Google sheets.
Having a form that supplies responses to a sheet, and for now I have to manually log in and remove the responses.
So a simple script that triggers every saturday, removing form responses from a sheet is what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Code to delete rows:

```
function deleteResponses() { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("File ID");
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[3]; 
  sheet.deleteRows(2, 200); 
};
```

To add code: Under the TOOLS menu, choose SCRIPT EDITOR.  Add this code.

Alternate code to clear the sheet:

```
function deleteResponses() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  sheet.clear();

};
```

Get your spreadsheet ID, and replace it in the "id" parameter.  Then under the RESOURCES menu, choose CURRENT PROJECTS TRIGGERS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I got error message "Can't find script function: myFunction"

Comment: The name of the function is `deleteResponses`, you need to use that name.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't have a thought of the id :)